# How to get the time used in the calculation each line of java code?

Tags: java, timer

I need to make loading bar[0-100%].

If mycode have 3 part(three methods).

```
void method A{

}
>>Calculate time  >>>Change to percent

void method B{

}
>>Calculate time  >>>Change to percent

void method C{

}
>>Calculate time  >>>Change to 100 percent(Finished)
```

Comment: Well, its not about "time", its about progress in the flow of the algorithm, so you can change the bars % depending on how much progress you think you have made after every method, since you cant be sure how long its going to take.

Comment: +1 to Edward. If you want a more accurate progress, then measure the time taken by each step, compute the respective percentages, and assume they'll be similar in the future by hardcoding these percentages (for example, if the execution on your machine leads to 1 second for method A, 2 seconds for method B and 2 seconds for method C, then hardcode the percentages 20%, 60% and 100%).